# Velocity framework servlet

Tags: velocity

I have a module written in servlets and needs to be recently moved to velocity framework
So in the process I am rewriting the web.xml to create velocity servlet object whcih calls
our original servlet .

Now if this has to be moved to

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>VeloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

How can we acheive this and what are all changes need to use the existing servlet as it is.
My Existing servlet looks like

```
<servlet-name>DataBridgeServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.jda.pwm.databridge.framework.common.DataBridgeServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jda.databridge.config.path</param-name>
    <param-value>d:/usr/databridge/conf</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This is loaded using the url http://localhost:8080/databridge/databridgeservlet

So in the newer case how velocity servlet calls this servlet

Comment: You need to expand a bit. What is the existing servlet? What are the servlet mappings? What do you mean by "use the existing servlet as it is"?

Comment: yeah i had modified a little can you chek now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at: [jpublish.org](http://jpublish.org) (I am the maintainer, therefore biased :) and replace your Servlet with a simple Action; scripting (BSH, JS) or Java, as you feel fit. My 0.2CAD

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the VelocityViewServlet in the Velocity Tools project?  This is a useful way of quickly getting Velocity pages on the web.

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view.servlet.html

You can subclass this for more customizability if desired.  And if nothing else, you can look at the source and use this as inspiration to make your own servlet.